# Maximize and minimize variance

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values in $\{0,1,...,10\}$. What are the minimum and maximum possible values of the variance of $X$?

I know $\mbox{Var}(X)=E[X^{2}]-E[X]^{2}$, but I'm unable to think how I can maximize or minimize it.

Comment: When is the variance the smallest? When the variable is not dispersed at all - that is when it is a constant. When is the variance the largest? When the variable is maximally dispersed - that it $X$ is symmetric Bernoully on $\{0,10\}$. To see this, scale everything down by $10$ and then $Var(X)\le E(X)-E(X)^2\le 1/4$ with the first equality iff $X\in\{0,1\}$ and second iff $E(X)=1/2$.

Comment: I worked out and got minimum value as zero by assigning $P(X=0)=1$ and $P(X=i)=0$ for all i in {$1,2..10$}. Also maximum value as 10 by assigning equal probability to each value of X. Am I right?

Comment: No. $E(X^2)-E(X)^2\le 10E(X)-E(X)^2\le 25$ with equality achieved iff $X$ is symmetric on $\{0,10\}$.